# Initializing 2d array in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, verbose

I am new to C and I'm trying to make a 2d array with 2 different cases.

1st is a verbose mode, with 2 arguments entered and the second one is the size of the array.

2nd is with the first argument being the size of the array.

The problem is that whenever I go with the 2nd option I keep getting "Segmentation fault: 11". But the 2 options work separately, if the other one is not in the code. Together, only the 1st option gives me a correct result

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
    char n1;
    sscanf (argv[1],"%c",&n1);
    */
    int status, status2, n, n2;

    status = sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
    status2 = sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &n2);
    if (strncmp(argv[1], "-v", 2) == 0) // if we are in VERBOSE MODE
    {
        int B[n2 + 1][n2 + 1]; // the verbose array
        for (int i = 0; i < n2 + 1; i++) // making every element into 0's
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2 + 1; j++)
            {
                B[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("we are in verbose mode\n");
        printf("argument 1 is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("argument 2 is %s\n", argv[2]);
        printf("2,2 is %d\n", B[2][2]); // testing
    }
    else if (status == 1)       // if an int is entered -> NOT VERBOSE MODE
    {
        printf("integer is %d\n", n);
        int B[n + 1][n + 1]; // declaring the array
        for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) // to make every element 0
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
            {
                B[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("1,1 is %d\n", B[1][1]); // testing
    }
    else    // if it's a wrong input -> print usage message
    {
        printf("Usage message\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here the else if statement code gives me the segmentation fault, but I don't see why. If I delete the "for" loops in the first "if" statement it'll work, but I need the array in both cases. (n+1 is the size because I want the rows/column numbers to match the array row/column numbers.)

Comment: What are the command lines you use when (a) it works and (b) when it fails?  You should really avoid so much duplication of code.  You should check on the value of `argc` before accessing either `argv[1]` or `argv[2]`.  Does your crash occur in `sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &n2)` when there is no `argv[2]` (it is a null pointer)?

Comment: First, automatic [VLAs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are dangerous and should not generally be used. Second, repeating essentially the same piece of code two or more times is a surefire way to end up with problems.